# Subdomain Enumeration using OWASPs Amass

Tags: api, subdomain, config, enumeration, haskell-snap-framework

Does anyone know where the config file for Amass is located if installed using snap or how to edit the config file if installed using snap? I know I can add my api keys to it, but don't know where the file is located in Ubuntu 20.04. Or do I just need to install it another way than snap? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by following these steps:-

first create a config file using:-

```
vim ~/.amass_config.ini
```

and then you can set the config file while executing amass using snap like this :-

```
amass -config ~/amass_config.ini
```